# relationship between nozzle radius and sound produced

Tags: mechanical-engineering

What is the relationship between nozzle size and sound produced? If there are references on it,kindly put it the comment space.

Comment: Perhaps search musical instruments : wind ie organs, trumpets, horns etc.... However, to save us repeating uselessly your work, what have you found already?

Comment: None of any significance

Comment: For example, is there any reduce on dB if we use bigger radius for outlet nozzle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imho the nozzle diameter should only affect the impedance, but not the frequency. The frequency is affected by the length of the nozzle. Everything else is really easy to look up using some google skills and keywords like "acoustic resonance".